# Can GPIO 9 to 14 be used in ESP32-S3-WROOM-2?

Tags: esp32

I want to use these GPIO for digital input/output, but I am not sure what are the things in the `Functions I don't know` column (ex: `FSPIHD`, `SUBSPICS0`)

| Name | No. | Type | Function | Functions I don't know |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IO9 | 17 | I/O/T | RTC_GPIO9, GPIO9, TOUCH9, ADC1_CH8 | FSPIHD, SUBSPIHD |
| IO10 | 18 | I/O/T | RTC_GPIO10, GPIO10, TOUCH10, ADC1_CH9 | FSPICS0, FSPIIO4, SUBSPICS0 |
| IO11 | 19 | I/O/T | RTC_GPIO11, GPIO11, TOUCH11, ADC2_CH0 | FSPID, FSPIIO5, SUBSPID |
| IO12 | 20 | I/O/T | RTC_GPIO12, GPIO12, TOUCH12, ADC2_CH1 | FSPICLK, FSPIIO6, SUBSPICLK |
| IO13 | 21 | I/O/T | RTC_GPIO13, GPIO13, TOUCH13, ADC2_CH2 | FSPIQ, FSPIIO7,SUBSPIQ |
| IO14 | 22 | I/O/T | RTC_GPIO14, GPIO14, TOUCH14, ADC2_CH3 | FSPIWP, FSPIDQS,SUBSPIWP |

This is the datasheet I am using: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3-wroom-2_datasheet_en.pdf

Can I use those pins? Is there any care I need to take?

[EDIT 1: Fixed datasheet link]

Comment: Esp32-s2 or s3? Datasheet is the s2

Comment: If S3: as how I think it works, you can use them. I think the internal (wroom internal) flash is connected to pins you can’t use. (Like with the esp32)

Comment: The table in your question and the linked datasheet do not match. Please update one or the other.

Comment: Thanks @RemyHx. I have updated the datasheet link, I was comparing both and pasted here the wrong one

Comment: Thanks @Codo. I have updated the datasheet link, I was comparing both and pasted here the wrong one

Comment: What table in the data sheet are you referring to where the pin description is split into "Function" and "Function*"?

Comment: @Codo. Sorry, I was not clear. I did the split of the table, to separate all the things I do not know what they are and I could not find any info about. The last column shows the "special" functions that I have no clue what they are

Comment: Even if you don't know what the special features are, they are still GPIO.

Comment: The ESP32 processor can routed the SPI signals to almost any pin, except if you use the highest speeds. Then very specific pins need to be used. Most or all of the pins you have single out are related to high speed SPI. If you don't use high speed SPI, you can use those pins as GPIO, ADC etc.

Comment: @Justme I think there are some pins that cannot be used because they are connected to the internal memory, and others that have to have certain value at boot. Is that correct?

Comment: @CarlosGarcia If you do a search on the datasheet for those pins, do you see they being used or being free? And the strap pins can be used, they just have to be at certain state at boot, it does not mean you can't use them.